# Netbeans salvou em cache uma classe excluida e não reconhece outra classe

Tags: java, netbeans

Tenho diferentes pacotes no meu projeto, e por engano, acabei criando duas classes com o mesmo nome, vamos supor Aluno.java, porém em pacotes diferentes.

Excluí uma delas, e mesmo depois de limpar o cache do Netbeans, ele não encontra mais a classe Aluno.java que restou no projeto.

Não sugere ela no autocomplete de "import br.com.meuprojeto.util [...]" e mesmo depois de limpar o cache da IDE, continuo sem conseguir importar a classe.

**EDIT**: Exemplificando melhor o problema. Tenha uma classe abstrata Aluno.java  e quero extender classes a partir dela. 
Acontece que, por engano, acabei criando outra classe chamada Aluno.java em um outro pacote do projeto.

Excluí essa segunda classe criada por engano, mas o Netbeans me parece que passou a não entender nenhuma referencia a Aluno.java, ou seja, a primeira classe Aluno.java do projeto continua existindo mas quando adiciono no meu projeto um "extends Aluno", ele não encontra dentro do meu projeto esta classe e na listagem de imports da classe, o "import br.com.meuprojeto.util" mostra Warning, mesmo que esse seja o caminho correto da onde a classe abstrata está.
Como teste, criei uma classe abstrata NewAluno.java, e ele entendeu ela perfeitamente.

- Tentei limpar o cache do Netbeans v8.1 apagando a pasta /Cache/8.1 que está, mas não funcionou.
- Apaguei o meu projeto da maquina, apaguei novamente a pasta, reiniciei a maquina, clonei novamente o projeto, e continua não entendendo a referencia.

Agora desinstalei o Netbeans, irei reiniciar a máquina e instalar o Netbeans novamente. Espero que desta forma o cache da IDE fique devidamente limpo, já que todas as outras tentativas foram falhas.

**EDIT 2** : Pior ainda desinstalar. O Netbeans não apaga todas as pastas e arquivos que ele utiliza. Estou tentando reinstalar mas agora travou a instalação e não vai. Ficou parado em 0%. Ou seja, se a IDE bugou, vai ficar bugada pra sempre rs. Limpar o cache não adianta, fechar o projeto e clonar tudo também nao adianta porque o problema é na IDE, reinstalar não adianta porque ele ainda sim não apaga tudo do seu computador e tentar instalar novamente pior ainda, porque fica travado e não vai.

**EDIT 3**: Código fonte, conforme solicitado.
O código é uma de classe JFrame que extende a classe abstrata Aluno.java. Estou fazendo um projeto Java Swing, e a classe abstrata Aluno.java traz algumas definições importantes para o projeto e por padrão, preciso que as telas JFrame se extendam de Aluno.java . Se eu criar uma classe NewAluno.java, o Netbeans entende a existência dessa classe normalmente (ou melhor, entendia... porque agora q desinstalei, piorou, estou sem trabalhar, igual escrevi ali no EDIT 2 em cima). Mas não posso refatorar todas as telas para que se extendam de NewAluno.java, até porque o problema é claramente na minha máquina já que meus colegas do projeto não tiveram nenhum problema quanto a isso.
Eu preciso de alguma maneira que faça o Netbeans voltar a enxergar a existência da classe Aluno.java original.

```
package br.com.meuprojeto.views;

/*A classe existe neste caminho, porém fica com warning no import,
 e como solução o Netbeans oferece: 'Importar de excluido'*/

import br.com.meuprojeto.util.Aluno; 
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Janela1 extends Aluno{

/**
 * Creates new form Janela1
 */
public Janela1() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: Certo. Eu tenho uma classe Aluno.java, e ela é uma classe abstrata, e quero extender classes a partir dela. Acontece que, por engano, acabei criando outra classe chamada Aluno.java em um outro pacote do projeto. Excluí essa segunda classe criada por engano, mas o Netbeans me parece que passou a não entender nenhuma referencia a Aluno.java, ou seja, a primeira classe Aluno.java do projeto continua existindo mas quando adiciono no meu projeto um "extends Aluno", ele não encontra dentro do meu projeto esta classe e na listagem de imports da classe, o "import br.projeto.aluno.Aluno" mostra Warning

Comment: Pronto, inclui um trecho do código.

Comment: Como assim uma tela estende um objeto? Isso ta meio estranho não? Ou uma janela é um tipo de aluno?

Comment: Não, veja bem. Não está estendendo objeto e sim a classe Aluno, que é um JFrame abstrato, com métodos abstratos, e quando eu crio novas telas JFrame, preciso que elas sejam 'extends' de Aluno para implementar os métodos.

Comment: Estás a usar Maven para gerir as dependências?

Comment: Isso eu entendi e não faz muito sentido. Uma tela é sempre uma tela, não deveria estender um tipo de objeto como foi feito, é como se você estivesse dizendo que uma tela é um tipo de aluno, faz sentido? Bom, não vou me alongar porque a duvida da pergunta nem era a respeito disso, e também pra não desvirtuar sua pergunta.

Comment: Entendo seu questionamento. É que as telas do meu projeto buscam informações para preencher tabelas e outros componentes através de alguns métodos request Json, por isso padronizo através de Aluno, assim os frames vão sempre trabalhar da mesma maneira, com as mesmas requisições. Faz sentido agora?

Comment: Não, ainda não fez sentido pra mim, mas se funciona perfeitamente para você, quem sou eu pra dizer se está errado ou não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução que eu tive para o problema de cache do Netbeans foi:

- Desinstalar o Netbeans
- Apagar os diretorios Netbeans em C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Roaming e C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local
- Apagar as pastas .nbi e .netbeans-derby em C:\Users\usuario, e apagar a pasta C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1
- Instalar novamente o Netbeans